# How to prove limits by using the formal definition (epsilon-delta)??

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I was told to prove the limit of $10-2x$ equals $16$ as $x\to-3$ using the formal definition (epsilon-delta).

This is what I tried so far, but I keep getting stuck. Can you help me solve this?

If $|x-(-3)|<\delta$ then $|(10-2x)-16|<\epsilon$.
Let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
If $|x+3|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then $-\frac{\epsilon}{2} <x+3 <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
So, $-\epsilon < 2x-6 <\epsilon$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Just write down the definition...

Comment: can you simplify $|10-2x-16|$ first? that should be enough...

Comment: You were doing fine, but where did $2x-6$ come from? What in fact is $|(10-2x)-16|$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does there exist an epsilon-delta proof of the limit for all polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485468/does-there-exist-an-epsilon-delta-proof-of-the-limit-for-all-polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

Well, these types of direct problems that are an application of the definition are always solved in the same way. You have to reverse the sentence of the definition of a limit in p of a funcion f:

x=/=p, |x-p|<delta ----> |f(x)-L|<épsilon

You'll always try this:
|f(x)-L|<épsilon <--->...<--->....<---> |x-p|<something in terms of épsilon.

So you proved that the definition applies, because for any épsilon, you found a delta in terms of épsilon(in fact it applies for any delta<this delta you found)

So stop here and try to do it by yourself.

E = Épsilon

|10-2x-16|<E
<--->
|-6-2x|<E
<--->
2|3+x|<E
<--->
|x-(-3)|<E/2

So, for any E, take a delta<=E/2, and then this is true:
|x-(-3)|<delta -----> |f(x)-f(-3)| < E
(the definition, it is true because of what I did in the beginning)
So it is continuous in -3

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Define $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
So, if
$$
|x-(-3)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
then
$$
|(10-2x)-16| = |2x+6| = 2|x+3| = 2|x-(-3)| < \epsilon
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to-3} (10-2x) = 16
$$
as required.